# jQuery DataTables and Knockout not binding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I've got an Ajax call that's returning a "Team". A team is comprised of a TeamName, LeagueName, and a list of FootballPlayers which have a Name, Position, and TeamName. The Ajax call is correctly returning the Team JSON properly and I'm about to make Knockout bindings to the properties directly on the Team. However, I want to bind a jQuery DataTable to the list of players, but have been unsuccessful in doing so. I can tell the DataTables call is being made, as I can see some of the DataTables controls like "Previous 1 Next" but no data is in the table. I can deploy what I have out to a publicly visible site if that'll be helpful. Thank you!

- jQuery: Version 2.1.1
- Knockout: Version 3.2.0
- DataTabes: Version
  1.10.4

### HTML Table

```
<table id="playerList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Player Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>
            <th>Position <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>
            <th>Team <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet" aria-hidden="true"></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--<tbody data-bind='foreach: PlayerList'>-->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.PlayerList.Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.PlayerList.SelectedPosition"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.PlayerList.TeamName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Controller Javascript

```
$('.retrieveTeam').click(function () {
        _getData('RetrieveTeam', JSON.stringify({ TeamKey: $(this).data("teamkey") }));

    });

function _getData(url, postdata) {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: postdata,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
    request.done(_requestDone);
    request.fail(_failedRequest)
}

function _requestDone(result)
{
    _bindTeam(result);
    my.Views.TeamView.showTeamInfo();
}

function _bindTeam(data) {
    if (!viewModel) {
        viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        my.Views.TeamView.applyDataTable('#playerList');
    } else {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
    }        
}
```

### View Javascript

```
var applyDataTable = function applyDataTable(element) {
    $(element).DataTable(
        {
            responsive: true,
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bLengthChange: false
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have done it... this fiddle uses a custom DataTablesForEach binding and also includes a fork of knockout... I have created a pull request with the knockout repository on github. If this solution helps you, please leave a comment on my pull request to get this merged into knockout 3.4.. thanks!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zachpainter77/4tLabu56/)

[pull request #1856 knockout/knockout repository on github](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1856)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.DataTablesForEach = {

        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
             var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
                if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
            });
            return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
            key = "DataTablesForEach_Initialized";

            var newValue = function () {
                return {
                    data: value.data || value,
                    beforeRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {

                        if (ko.utils.domData.get(element, key)) {
                            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().clear();
                            $(element).closest('table').DataTable().destroy();
                        }
                    },
                    afterRenderAll: function (el, index, data) {
                        $(element).closest('table').DataTable(value.options);
                    }

                };
            };

            ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, newValue, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

            //if we have not previously marked this as initialized and there is currently items in the array, then cache on the element that it has been initialized
            if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (value.data || value.length)) {
                ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
            }

            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
```